# Reader / Writer Lock with timeout using conditional variable

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking

How to write a Reader/Writer lock with timeout, using conditional variables in C/C++?

Comment: this will vary with platform...

Comment: I don't believe your edit makes sense.  The answer is inherently platform-dependent, a platform independent library is nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking for a library, [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the source of Java's implementation [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Just grab the [JDK](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u11-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) unpack the src.zip file and search for the source.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: The solution should be in C/C++

Comment: It's ok. At least you can borrow some ideas from Java's implementation

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for such things in current standard C++, although C++0x will have some threading support (I haven't checked to see how much).  Therefore, any answer would have to be platform-dependent, using platform in a very general sense.

It is possible to write libraries that will behave similarly across different underlying systems, and there are quite a few cross-platform libraries.  (These are subject to inefficiencies, of course, if the capabilities of the underlying platforms are different.)  There could be a generally accepted C++ threading library that would work on Windows and Unix-based systems (which is almost anything you'd be running on a desktop nowadays), but I don't know of one offhand.

Therefore, this question can't really be answered as asked.  It would be necessary to answer it on a particular platform or library, and none is specified.  It would make sense if coupled with a request for a library recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) library. Specifically: `shared_mutex` and `upgradeable_mutex` objects.